# Correct name of an agreement used as a template for individual ones

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, taxonomy

I can't decide on the most preferred taxonomy regarding agreements. A chain can sign an agreement that each of its franchises can suborder and sign their own individual deal. When I looked it up, I got two suggestions (and can add others by my own). Now I'm sitting here scratching my head indecisive on which one to pick.

1. General agreement
2. Framework agreement
3. Collective agreement
4. Group agreement
5. Suborderable agreement

Which would be the most preferred term for such an agreement? I'm formostly looking for a formal nomenclature and American English is preferred (if there's any difference).

## Edit

The said agreement will also be used for individuals (e.g. members of a labor union, where the union is the signer, while the members are suborderers). Franchise was just an example (perhaps poorly chosen).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general contract that covers many aspects of the relationship between two parties, but which is then subject to specific agreements for particular projects of aspects of that telationship is often called a **master agreement** or **[master service agreement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_service_agreements)**.

**SUPPLEMENT**

In light of the additional information provided in the edited question, I think **[master contract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_contract_%28labor%29)** may be a good choice

> Although a master contract governs the general terms of employment that apply uniformly across the company or industry, master contracts often provide for local terms to be negotiated

While *franchise agreements* have some similar characteristics describing the relationship between a chain or sponsor and individual units, not all chain relationships are franchises. The term *franchise* has very specific legal implications and actually varies from state to state.

Answer (score 1):

In the context you mentioned, I'm pretty sure it's a "franchise agreement":

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franchise_agreement

Comment: Please see my edit. I've been unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this [information](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Franchise%20agreement,%20General%20agreement,%20Framework%20agreement,%20Collective%20agreement,%20Group%20agreement,%20Suborderable%20agreement&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4;,Franchise%20agreement;,c0;,s0;;franchise%20agreement;,c0;;Franchise%20Agreement;,c0;;FRANCHISE%20AGREEMENT;,c0;;Franchise%20agreement;,c0;.t4;,General%20agreement;,c0;,s0;;general%20agreement;,c0;;General%20Agreement;,c0;;General%20agreement;,c0;.t4;,Framework%20agreement;,c0;,s0;;framework%20agreement;,c0;;Framework%20Agreement;,c0;;Framework%20agreement;,c0;;FRAMEWORK%20AGREEMENT;,c0;.t4;,Collective%20agreement;,c0;,s0;;collective%20agreement;,c0;;Collective%20Agreement;,c0;;COLLECTIVE%20AGREEMENT;,c0;;Collective%20agreement;,c0;.t4;,Group%20agreement;,c0;,s0;;group%20agreement;,c0;;Group%20Agreement;,c0;;Group%20agreement;,c0;;GROUP%20AGREEMENT;,c0), I'd go with "franchise agreement."

Comment: Please see my edit. I've been unclear.